IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1 - Change the encoding used to view a file
I want to  Change the encoding used to view a file, but the encoding option is disabled

the bottom right of the IJ window is read-only:


At the bottom right of the IJ window there is a field showing the current file encoding.  You should be able to click on that and change it.

Do you see this issue only on *.properties files? If so, the lock on status bar is by design, and the encoding can be changed here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/properties-files.html#configure-default-encoding-for-properties-files

Your file contains UTF-8 Byte order mark. It's  (supposedly) a reason why the option File encoding is disabled…

go to preferences -> File encodins:

